# Updating live web chat php

Tags: php, chat

So, I am making live web chat (file based), soo I got this file chat_log.txt, when I read that file in php I must always refresh to get chat_log.txt content. I need my code to be dynamic and update itself soo it can get chat_log content live. (sorry for bad English)

Comment: You will need ajax, can you give us your actual code ?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. It is not a place to dump your to-do/requirements list.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a good look at ajax. Which is used to make calls to the server "behind the scenes" If you are using jquery it's quite simple. See here for further reading on Ajax: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

Comment: Yes with that you can repeat a snippet of code for example evert 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

If your not that big of a fan of jQuery, you could use webSockets
https://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/chat-using-websocket-php-socket

That's an example without a file based system. But you can alter the code and make the chat_log.txt file

Comment: I find it hard to install because I am not using localhost (xampp) I am using hosting server.